# Routing with slashes in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am trying to use pushState routing in Backbone.js

The problem is that when I try to use routes which contain slashes in between the links, the router function wouldn't get called and the console would show an error:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
    "work/mobileapps": "showPortfolio"
     },

    showPortfolio: function(){
        alert('Show Portfolio');
}
```

The showPortfolio function never gets called in this case. I've also tried to do it with parameters, like this:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
    "work/:section": "showPortfolio"
     },

    showPortfolio: function(){
        alert('Show Portfolio');
}
```

but the problem still remains the same.

However, if I change the route to something like this:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
    "work-mobileapps": "showPortfolio"
     },

    showPortfolio: function(){
        alert('Show Portfolio');
}
```

it starts to work.

So it seems like there's some problem with the slashes. Please help and let me know what mistake I am making.

Thanks!

Here's the full code:

```
//Set variables according to production/development environment
var production = 0;
var rootpath = (production) ? "/" : "Websitev2/code";
//--------------------------------------------------------------


var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "work/mobileapps": "showPortfolio",
        "about": "showAbout",
        "work": "showWork",
        "": "showHome"
    },

    showPortfolio: function(){

        alert('Show Portfolio');

        //$("#work-content").empty();
    },

    showAbout: function () {

        alert('Show About');



    },

    showWork: function () {

        alert('Show Work');
    },

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.router = new Router();
    Backbone.history.start({
        pushState: true,
        root: rootpath
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my very limited experience, have you tried:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        'work(/:section)': 'showPortfolio'
    },

    showPortfolio: function(section){
        alert('Show Portfolio ' + section);
    }
});
```

As noted in the comments, you need to reference routes with a hash:

`http://localhost/Websitev2/code/#work/mobileapps`

Comment: Can you post your full code, as this is how you use routes, there must be a problem with something else in your code.

Comment: Are you accessing the route with `#work/mobileapps`? I've tested your code and it works fine...

Comment: That's not how routing works. It's looking for a domain directory there. You need to use `http://localhost/Websitev2/code/#work/mobileapps`

Comment: I've updated the answer if using the hash fixed your problem. Feel free to mark it as correct.